# How to Align the text of my label?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I want to align the text of my label to right aligned. But the problem is my label is in UITableVIewCell and i am using 'Value1' of UITableViewCell. So i want to align detailText label to the right side of the cell but sometimes the labels is in two or three lines so in that case i want the next line of the label to be left aligned so that it looks the next line is starting from left.

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom tableview cells. Add a UITableViewCell class to your project and call it CustomCell, create a TableViewCell in Iterface Builder. Add two Labels, One right aligned called "label1", the other one left aligned called "label2", or do what ever you want, Then you can use it in your main class like this:

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

cell.label1.text = @"some rightAlignedText";
cell.label2.text = @"some leftAlignedText";

return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at a different cell type or create your own custom one because as far as I know, the way each table cell is laid out is set in stone